# Overload resolution picks incompatible generic method instead of compatible base class method

Tags: c#, overloading

I ran in an overloading resolution problem which I did not expect. Apparently the compiler rather resolves a call to the `MyPrint` method passing `"Hello world"` to the `MyPrint<T>(T : struct)` in the derived class than to the `MyPrint(string)` defined in the base class. And since the method that the resolver chose will not accept the string, I get a compiler error.

I suppose it has to do with the Brittle Base Class problem as [Jon Skeet wrote in his book](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx), and [Eric Lippert on his blog](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/04/future-breaking-changes-part-three.aspx). Lippert quotes the standard as saying:

> Methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived
>   class is applicable.

But I don't see any method in the derived class being applicable, and neither does the compiler judging from the error. I would like to know two things: why does it work this way, and how can I let C# do what I want it to do again?

Contrived example demonstrating the problem:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();

        d.MyPrint(10);

        // ERROR: The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type
        // in order to use it as parameter 'T'
        // in the generic type or method 'Derived.MyPrint<T>(T)'.
        d.MyPrint("Hello world!");
    }
}

class Base
{
    // I print only strings.
    public void MyPrint(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("String: " + value);
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    // I print any primitive type, enums and DateTime,
    // but NOT string (since that is not a value type).
    public void MyPrint<T>(T value)
        where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IConvertible: " + value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: MyPrint<T> looks like MyPrint<string> during overload resolution, and then later fails because the constraints are not met. A result of "constraints are not part of the signature", I guess

Comment: It would be good to put that as an answer instead than a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found half of the reason, but you also need [Constraints are not part of the signature.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx) Combined with "Methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable", you get that during overload resolution there are two methods that look like `MyPrint(string)` and are therefore applicable, so the one in the most-derived class is chosen. Only after that is the constraint checked, which then fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work, if you define this in your derived class:

```
public new void MyPrint(string value)
{
    base.MyPrint(value);
}
```

As for the "why", sorry I don't know. Probably the [C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) can help to answer this question.